# bxSlider short PagerType and maxSlides counting issue

Tags: bxslider

I'm currently calling bxslider with both the pager and min/max slide options.

The issue I'm having is that it's not counting my slides correctly, it seems to be counting the current slide (correct) and the "next" amount of slides instead of the total. How do I get the total instead?

https://jsfiddle.net/uLc6qrmn/

HTML:

```
<ul class="carousel-slider">
    <li><img src="assets/images/cms-images/gallery.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="assets/images/cms-images/gallery.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="assets/images/cms-images/gallery.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="assets/images/cms-images/gallery.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="assets/images/cms-images/gallery.jpg" alt=""/></li>
</ul>
```

bxSlider call:

```
 $('.carousel-slider').bxSlider({
    auto: false,
    pager: true,
    pagerType: 'short',
    minSlides: 3,
    maxSlides: 3,
    moveSlides:1,
    slideWidth: 800,
    slideMargin: 40
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't find an [issue](https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/issues) (atm 333 issues), it seems there's a bug. Provided is a workaround that basically creates a new pager that behaves properly. Details are commented in Fiddle and Snippet.

<kbd>[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/53uww5e1/1/)</kbd>

#### SNIPPET

```js
$(function() {
  var bx = $('.carousel-slider').bxSlider({
    auto: false,
    pager: false,
    //pagerType: 'short',
    minSlides: 3,
    maxSlides: 3,
    moveSlides: 1,
    /* Not required but, could be useful */
    shrinkItems: true,
    slideWidth: 800,
    slideMargin: 40,
    /* Callback will update active slide index after a transition */
    onSlideAfter: counter,
    /* Callback will insert the new pager element when loading */
    onSliderLoad: init
  });

  function init() {
    $('.bx-controls').after('<nav id="counter">1 / 5</nav>');
  }

  function counter() {
    $('#counter').text((bx.getCurrentSlide() + 1) + ' / ' + bx.getSlideCount());
  }

});
```

```css
/* Design #counter however you want */

#counter {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font: 400 16px/1.5 verdana;
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2em;
  color: #9f9f9f;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ul class="carousel-slider">
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x500?text=1">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x500?text=2">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x500?text=3">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x500?text=4">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x500?text=5">
  </li>
</ul>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js'></script>
```